# Will quic be dynamic adaptive according to MTU packet size specially in ipv6

Tags: ipv6

According to IPv6 network and dynamic Path MTU than can be overcome 1500, will QUIC be opened in order to do not stay at 1350 bytes per packet. The goal would be to fill in more bytes per packet in order to get more bandwidth according to same the packet per second ratio inside network elements
Thks

Answer (score 0):

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-quic-transport-29#section-14:

> The QUIC maximum packet size is the largest size of QUIC packet that
> can be sent across a network path using a single packet.  Any maximum
> packet size larger than 1200 bytes can be discovered using Path
> Maximum Transmission Unit Discovery (PMTUD; see Section 14.2.1) or
> Datagram Packetization Layer PMTU Discovery (DPLPMTUD; see Section
> 14.3).

So Quic maximum packet size *may* be determined dynamically, but it's up to the endpoints to decide.